# How to tell reposurgeon to convert a SVN repository having tags with spaces?

Tags: git, svn, migration, reposurgeon

I try to use reposurgeon 4.0 to convert a SVN repository having tags with spaces (e.g. `V 4.1.x snapshot`).

Let's consider that I actually need such tags (and there are a tenth). To delete these tags is not an option. Also, I don't want to use another tool as I'd like to evaluate this one.

I'd like to tell the tool to rename this as V_4.1.x_snapshot and thus I try to use a command in the .lift file.
I tried several syntax listed below, but it always fails with a script abort message on the conversion.log file.

```
tag V 4.1.x snapshot rename V_4.1.x_snapshot
tag V\ 4.1.x\ snapshot rename V_4.1.x_snapshot
tag 'V 4.1.x snapshot' rename V_4.1.x_snapshot
tag [V\s4.1.x\snapshot] rename V_4.1.x_snapshot
```

The latter one was a trial assuming that a regexp could have been used there.

Also, I'd like to understand how I could tell reposurgeon to keep empty folders.

Could someone help on this ?
Best Regards
J-L